# 100 users works fine, for 200 it gives "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException" error with "Remote host closed connection during handshake" message

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, jmeter, sslhandshakeexception

I've this JMX script that when I run for 100 virtual users, using my laptop, it works just fine without any errors. [Here](https://a.blazemeter.com/app/?public-token=gZS5uUZhmDoEkep072NI2lXoOsa1eZGqqNO19grjTYtmNp5k8F#masters/15308063/summary) is the BlazeMeter report for the run. But when I increase the virtual users to 200, it is giving me this SSLHandshakeException error. Please find the BlazeMeter error report [here](https://a.blazemeter.com/app/?public-token=rsEKNv3nVFnxeLBPggMLiMhPnwAxTiZh14070Hwgc8lEnZqSR9#masters/15309702/summary).

To verify, the system can handle 200 virtual users, I've used four AWS JMeter machines (giving each to load 50 virtual users) and ran the same script, found no issues. [Here](https://a.blazemeter.com/app/?public-token=U9lOB0gzsk9PUk95UDKgGDbXUqSx8ygUMu4b7jptQdu7V9Cf3A#masters/15308141/summary) is the report for this run.

I'm wondering what might go wrong when I run it for 200 virtual users from my laptop. Can anyone please help me? What can cause this?

Please note, I'm using a 16GB RAM machine (assigned 10GB of ram to JMeter), updated Jmeter properties file ("httpclient4.retrycount=1") and 'hc.parameters'  (enabled "http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true" and increased socket timeout "http.socket.timeout$Integer=600000") file in the \bin folder.

Thanks in advance!
--Ishti

Comment: How does it behave if you use HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Comment: For error case, Are you running scripts from JMeter installed on your local machine OR from BlazeMeter cloud service. Just want to confirm.

Comment: EJP, the server requires HTTPS, didn't try with HTTP. TestingWithArif, for the error cases, I'm running scripts from JMeter installed on my local machine, NOT from BlazeMeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given response time differences for local and AWS runs (1.55s vs 0.6s) and the fact load does not increase as virtual users number grows I would expect that your laptop either doesn't have enough hardware resources in order to kick off 200 concurrent users or you don't have enough network bandwidth. Check JMeter JVM stats using [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) or something like it and main OS metrics using i.e. [Windows Performance Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx) or equivalent.

Also if you're not load testing `stgbasalt.peopleanswers.com` domain, it's better to exclude it (as well as other external domains) from your test plan. If it comes through embedded resources - filter it via "URLs must match" section, see [Excluding Domains From The Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) guide for more information.